# Reading data from Azure Table Storage in HDInsight

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-hdinsight

I'd like to use Azure Table Storage as the data source for my Hadoop application running on HDInsight. I only found [this library](https://github.com/mooso/azure-tables-hadoop/tree/master/src) by MSFT however there is not enough documentation. I have a few questions regarding sourcing from Azure Table:

1) How data chunks are formed? Let's, can I give records from one partition to each mapper? If yes, what happens if the partition contains lots of records? If not, how that works?

2) Can a Hadoop application also output to Azure Table?

3) Can a Hadoop job source data from two (or more) Azure Tables? If so, how to distinguish between them in the mapper? e.g. when sourcing data from multiple file, we can distinguish the records based on the input file name.

Comment: If you are using HDInsight, you are probably coding in Java meaning you would want to check out the Azure Storage [Java client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java). For best practices for using Azure Storage Tables please check out this best practices [guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm mainly concerned about getting data in HDInsight. The Azure Storage Java Client would be the underlying layer. I need a layer on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post documents it a bit and answers your question about mappers:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mostlytrue/archive/2014/04/04/analyzing-azure-table-storage-data-with-hdinsight.aspx

As far as I know you can't insert to Azure Table Storage using this library.

I believe you can read from two tables by creating two external tables and joining them in Hive.

Comment: I've already read this blog post, but it's very short and does not explain the details.

Comment: How can I change the azure-tables-hadoop library such that mapper get entities belonging to more than just one partitionkey? The default behavior is that each mapper is given entities for one partitionkey.

Comment: @H.Z. Luckily it is open source code so you can change it however you see fit.

Comment: Yes, But I couldn't quite understand how I should do that. As far as I understood I should extends BaseAzureTablePartitioner class an write my own class. I got two problems 1) what logic I should put into MyCustomizedAzureTablePartitioner class so that each mapper takes more than one partition 2) how can I make the library to use MyCustomizedAzureTablePartitioner. Could you help me with that?